# The document is not a function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing in JavaScript. I have this if statement:

```
var rightsRef = db.collection("users").document(uid).collection("rights");
        if(createDocumentWithId(rightsRef, "readGrades", "false", null, null, null, null) === true) {
          window.location.href = "../public/main/main_index.html";
        }
```

And here is the function who should add the values in cloud firestore:

```
function createDocumentWithoutId(var databaseRef, var titleValue1, var contentValue1, var titleValue2, var contentValue2, var titleValue3, var contentValue3) {
  databaseRef.add({
    titleValue1: contentValue1,
    titleValue2: contentValue2,
    titleValue3: contentValue3,
  }).then(function() {
    return true;
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
    return false;
  });
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: db.collection(...).document is not a function
```

Comment: firebase [appears to not have a document method on a collection, but it does have .doc()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I say this all tentatively because I don't actually use Firebase, but based off of the error you had, `db.collection("users")` is returning an object that didn't have the `document` property.

When I looked briefly at the firebase api documentation, the API for getting a document reference looks to be `doc` and not `document` as seen [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document)

Also, looking [at the api docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference), you can see that a collection reference only has a function called `doc`.

Answer (score 0):

`db.collection("users")` returns a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference) object.  As you can see from the API documentation, it doesn't have a method called `document()`.  It does have a method called [doc()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc), which is what you want.  You're probably confusing the Firestore JavaScript API with the Java API.